# Calculate sum of series $\sum \frac{n(n-1)}{5^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

So I was trying to calculate the sum of the following serie :
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n(n-1)}{5^n}
$$
I'm not sure how to do it, but I think its using its derivative and then tending n to infinity. I can only go that far :
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^n &= \frac{1-(1/5)^{n+1}}{1-(1/5)} \\
&= \frac{5(1-(1/5)^{n+1})}{4} \\
&=\frac54 - \frac14 \times \left(\frac15\right)^n 
\end{aligned}
$$
but then, when I derive, I get something times log something and I dont think it's the way I'm supposed to solve this.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Write diown $\sum \frac {x^{n}}{5^{n}}$ and differentiate twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac1{1-x} \tag1
$$

which converges for $|x| < 1$.  Then differenciate $f$ two times in order to get the factors $n$ and $n-1$ in front of $x^n$, and calculate $f''(1/5)$:

$$
f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1} = \frac1{(1-x)^2} \tag2
$$

$$
f''(x) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)x^{n-2} = 2\frac1{(1-x)^3} \tag3
$$

Then observe that for the desired sum $S$ we have:
$$\begin{align}
S = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n(n-1)}{5^n} 
&= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n(n-1)}{5^n}\tag4 \\
&= \frac1{5^2}\cdot\underbrace{\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n(n-1)}{5^{n-2}}}_{\textstyle =  f''\left(\frac15\right)} \\
&= \frac5{2^5}
\end{align}$$

And in your approach, you cannot differentiate with respect to $n$ because it is not a continuous variable, and $n$ is not a free variable.

Comment: Thank you very much !